# how to retrieve data from a table which has no data from left table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 2 tables: `user` and  `address`

I want to query and show all users from table `user` which have no associated `address`'.

My query is below, but it does not work probably due to `having` clause. It throws an error instead.

```
select * from user_application
join user_address on user_address.user_id = user_application.user_id
where address_type = 0
having count(user_address.user_id) = 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select * 
from user_application as u1
where not exists (select 1
                  from user_address as u2
                  where u2.user_id = u1.user_id)
```

Comment: This is the equivalent of a left join with a null check

Answer (score 3):

**Approach:** Using LEFT JOIN with NULL check

```
select * from user_application
left join user_address on user_address.user_id = user_application.user_id
and  address_type = 0 where user_address.userid is NULL
```

**Explanation:**

We figure out a set of all users with their address information added due to LEFT JOIN and then by using WHERE clause we filter out to desired set of records of user who do not have address

On why your query did not work, because you used a `having` without `group by`. Corrected syntax is

```
select 
  user_application.user_id -- you can only select the column used in group by 
 from user_application
 join user_address on user_address.user_id = user_application.user_id
where address_type = 0
group by user_application.user_id
having sum(case when user_address.user_id is null then 0 else 1 end) = 0
```

Comment: thanks for response, i tried your solution, it worked too, it return the same result with other's answer. i will upvote it thanks!

Comment: I believe that the LEFT JOIN approach @DhruvJoshi suggested is way better, it's a simple JOIN operation where the GROUP/HAVING approach probably requires more overhead. But you should check the exstimated query plan to verify it.